# Org Mode extension to colorize scheduled entries/subtrees?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I wonder if there is a theme/setting to gray out entries scheduled in the future in an Org file. This would help visually sift through stuff that's not actionable.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option would be to use the org-sparse-tree with the "match" option (C-c / m) and then use the following regular expression:

```
-SCHEDULED={.}-SCHEDULED>"<today>"
```

This will show you all headlines either having no schedules or headlines having schedules in the past.

Followed by the command org-kill-note-or-show-branches (C-c C-k), you will get all your headlines in a file and the ones that are interesting to you, will be highlighted by Emacs.

Maybe this helps.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work. -SCHEDULED passed to the "match" subtree collapses all headings. Would you have a tutorial on how the sparse trees work? The one I found is https://orgmode.org/manual/Sparse-Trees.html yet it does not capture the matching.